# Eclipse - Install new software not showing p2 repository

Tags: eclipse, installation

I'm experiencing serious issue with the Eclipse 'Install new software' and 'Update' Dialogs.

In fact they seem to do nothing.

With a brand new Eclipse Java EE Juno 4.2 I can't install new software. I try to retrieve the contents of 'Juno - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno' but it's stuck all the time. Often is stops doing anything around 31% but sometimes it reaches 38% after 20 minutes but there must be something wrong.

I unticked all the options and also deactivated firewall and antivir and tried to alter the network configurations in eclipse with no effect.

I'm not behind a proxy.

Somebody got a solution on this?

Regards

The Error Log has plenty entries mainly like this:

Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/201206270900/artifacts.jar.

Unknown Host: http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/patches/drops/R3.4.1/P-3.4.1-20121112163420/repository/content.xml

Connection to http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/juno/p2.index failed on Connection reset. Retry attempt 0 started

Connection to http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/patches/drops/R3.4.1/P-3.4.1-20121112163420/repository/p2.index failed on Connection reset. Retry attempt 0 started

Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/201206270900/content.jar.

Connection to http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/201209280900/p2.index failed on Connection reset. Retry attempt 0 started

Comment: could you start eclipse with -clear command line option (just in case...) open error log, clear previous errors and try opening the update dialog again. Check if there is any error in the error log.

Comment: I tried http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno and it managed to fetch everything from the server. No install has been made though.

Comment: it's not working for me... it's stuck all the time. Are you using eclipse for java ee?

Comment: no, I was just curious whether the p2 site was working properly, or at least one can fetch the repository information, because the errors you found made me suspicious

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Indigo. Can't download any updates or new software (in my case m2e). Can't update as well. It stays at 38% forever, always cycling through several packages trying to fetch them.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try with the following option in your STS.ini file, it worked for me:

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have antivirus (particularly Kaspersky) running. May have to pause your AV program as it could block the process.